# Reload ExpandableListView items after adapter modified

Tags: android, adapter, expandablelistview

I have to delete child item in my expandablelistview.
My attempt was:
1. Data from adapter is removed successfully.
2. Tried to rebuild listview with 'm_list.invalidateViews()'
Result is: exceptuion: index out of range.

Looking at debuger - value of childPosition is bigger than count of adapter data.Strange.
Usualy getChildView is called for each item in adapter. So why getChildView is called with childPosition bigger than data size?

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't work??

Comment: It works. Strange fact is: adapter have 3 items, but getChildView is called for 4.....Probably view was build with cached data, not real from adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the dataset from which you are loading list, and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Tried notifyDataSetChanged - it os OK. Probably InvalidateViews rebuild view, but works with cached data from adapter :(

Comment: same thing happened to me